# „so daß“ versus „sodass“ versus „so dass“

Tags: spelling, compound, reformed-orthography

Oftmals, wenn ich nicht weiter weiß, suche ich im Internet die Empfehlungen der Seite [`www.korrekturen.de`](http://www.korrekturen.de/) auf. Hier findet man auf einigen Unterseiten Tabellen, die einem die Schreibweisen der alten Rechtschreibung bis 1996, die der neuen Rechtschreibung von 1996 bis 2004/2006 und die neuen Rechtschreibung seit 2004/2006 aufzeigen.

[Eine Seite habe ich hierzu auch gefunden, die sich mit der alten Rechtschreibung „so daß“ und den neuen Varianten „sodass“ und „so dass“ beschäftigt.](https://www.korrekturen.de/wortliste/sodass.shtml) Laut aktuellem Stand sind „sodass“ und „so dass“ zulässig. Von `www.korrekturen.de` wird allerdings die Schreibweise „so dass“ empfohlen. Leider steht aber nicht dabei, weshalb genau diese Schreibweise empfohlen wird und nicht die Schreibweise „sodass“.

Oft orientiert sich `www.korrekturen.de` an der alten Rechtschreibung und gibt nur selten die Empfehlung es mit neuartigen Varianten der neuen Rechtschreibung zu versuchen. In diesem Falle rät man also zur Getrenntschreibung, wie auch schon in der alten Rechtschreibung.

Was aber ist der Grund, weshalb es eindeutiger sein sollte „so dass“ statt „sodass“ zu schreiben? Dies scheint mir nämlich oftmals der Grund zu sein, weshalb `www.korrekturen.de` die eine oder andere Schreibweise empfiehlt: Eindeutigkeit.

Answer (score 1):

Es steht doch auf der verlinkten Website: "Die empfohlenen Schreibweisen von korrekturen.de folgen den Empfehlungen der Wörterbuchredaktionen von Duden und/oder Wahrig und sind stets konform zum Regelwerk des Rats der deutschen Rechtschreibung 2006. Näheres hierzu entnehmen Sie bitte der Übersichtsseite." Ich denke, das ist alles was hinter der orangfarbenen Makierung in diesem Fall steht. Sowohl Duden als auch Wahrig empfehlen es so.

Ich finde es lustig, dass nicht die empfohlene Schreibweise im Titel der korrekturen.de-Seite gelistet ist.

Comment: Jetzt weiß ich zumindest schon einmal das. Aber *weshalb* die eine Schreibweise empfohlen wird, weiß ich immer noch nicht. Das würde mich nämlich interessieren.